# UK Tier 2 Visa - Reenter UK after visa expiry

Tags: visas, uk, passports, legal

I am a Malaysian and I have a Tier 2 Skilled Migrant visa that will be expiring on **April 20** and I plan to leave on 15 April to go for a vacation in Poland before I leave Europe for good and go home to Malaysia.

However, my company has booked for me a flight home that will depart from London Heathrow airport on **April 25**, when my visa would already have expired and I could no longer re-enter using my visa when I return from my vacation.

My plan as of now is to try to re-enter as a visitor but I have the following questions:

1. Would I be able to properly exit UK by just going to Europe for a vacation? As in getting my passport stamped for exit so I can re-enter as a visitor? I have this doubt as I have heard before that it is border-less between EU and UK.
2. I have been advised by my agent that re-entering so soon is likely to cause the officer to question, or even refuse my entry as they would suspect my intention to leave the UK, is this true?
3. Would there be any difference with regard to my chances of clearing immigration if I enter the same day or one day before my flight and show my flight ticket home to prove my intention to leave? I have read about transit visa and my intention of reentry is really only a transit but I am a Malaysian and I do not need a transit visa to enter UK, is there such a thing as entering as a "transitor" rather than visitor to convince them it's just a short stopover?

Comment: T2 questions are better suited for Expats http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @GayotFow seems to be about a transit visa tough, I've read it twice though and I'm still confused

Comment: @blackbird57, yeah but different domain.  There's an enforced cooling off period following some T2 expiries and we don't know the relevant questions to ask because we're not Expats :)

Comment: @GayotFow The cooling-ff period is only applicable to the visa itself and I should be able to re-enter using another type of visa, or as a visitor